# Не выводит одно слово при формировании списка словосочетаний

Tags: java

Из кода выводится список сформированных по длине словосочетания, которые в дальнейшем печатаются на image.
Не могу придумать условие, чтобы при этом условии печатало и одно слово. Может, нужен какой-то дополнительный `if`?

```
private List<String> divideText(String text) {
    String[] resSplit = text.split(" ");
    List<String> res = new LinkedList<String>();
    String resultForRes = "";
    int countLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < resSplit.length; i++) {
        resultForRes += resSplit[i] + " ";
        countLength = resultForRes.length();
        if (countLength >= 8) {
            res.add(0, resultForRes);
            resultForRes = "";
            countLength = 0;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: "чтобы при этом условии печатало и одно слово" - поясните, пожалуйста

Comment: Согласен, не совсем понятно. Предполагается, если есть слово, которое меньше "допустимой" длины, на данный момент она 8, эта длина ограничена размерами image, в условие не заходит и не отрабатывает запись в список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если после цикла в `resultForRes` что-то осталось, то это тоже стоит добавить в список (`if` после `for`). Это поможет и в ситуации, при которой в тексте всего одного слово с длиной менее 7 символов (или несколько слов, суммарная длина которых вместе с пробелами после них меньше 8 символов), и в ситуации, при которой последнее слово не попало в `res` из-за недостаточной длины.

```
private List<String> divideText(String text)
{
    String[] resSplit = text.split(" ");
    List<String> res = new LinkedList<>();
    String resultForRes = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < resSplit.length; i++)
    {
        resultForRes += resSplit[i] + " ";
        if (resultForRes.length() >= 8)
        {
            res.add(0, resultForRes);
            resultForRes = "";
        }
    }
    if (!resultForRes.isEmpty())
    {
        res.add(0, resultForRes);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Также стоит рассмотреть проблему того, что у вас пробелы добавляются не только между словами в словосочетании, но и после последнего слова. По идее, для первого слова в словосочетании должно быть `resultForRes = resSplit[i]`, а для последующих - `resultForRes += " " + resSplit[i]`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я постараюсь учесть это